# Detect graphs in a set of arbitrary edges

Tags: graph-theory

I've got a set of potentially unrelated edges and need to transform it into graphs. For example, the set contains $A\leftrightarrow B$ and $Z\leftrightarrow X$.  $A$ and $B$ are not connected with $Z$ and $X$, so I expect to detect two isolated graphs.  Is there a specific name for an operation/algorithm that makes such detection? I'm looking at a big programming library with lots of algorithms, but am lost in the terminology.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, are you looking to detect [connected components](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(graph_theory)) of a graph? If yes, then you can use [depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search) algorithms.

Comment: @an4s TIL it's called connected components. And yes, I can see now how to apply DFS/BFS, thank you.